# How can I map raw buffer using multi-dimensional array?

Tags: c++, embedded, x86-64

I'd like to know the best practice for mapping an HW buffer in software.

Let's say my contiguous buffer's map is :

```
+--------+  <- myPtr
|  128b  | #0
+--------+
|  128b  | #1
+--------+
|  128b  | #2
+--------+
|  128b  | #3
+--------+
```

In C++ I'd use:

```cpp
void *myPtr;
uint8_t (*buffer)[16][4]=nullptr;

myPtr = mmap(/*..*/);
buffer = static_cast<uint8_t (*)[16][4]>(myPtr);
```

I can select one of the four sub-buffers using `buffer[0] ... buffer[3]`.

Now let's say I want to assign 32b with 64b/8B offset of the buffer #1, can I do:

```cpp
uint32_t value=4546954;
*buffer[1][8] = value;
```

- Is the address of `buffer` and `buffer->data` same?
- Is there a better way to map my data from a `void* ptr`?

I'd like to avoid pointer arithmetic, to let the compiler doing the job and checking for me everything it can check.

*I target exclusively **x86-64** CPUs (Intel).*

Comment: `memcpy` can be a good way to express a multi-byte store into a `char[]` buffer, without violating strict-aliasing.  It should optimize to just a `mov` store in asm.  If you only ever want to use 8-bit and 32-bit accesses, you could just cast to `uint32_t (*)[4][4]` or something and use that for the DWORD stores.  Accesses via the `char[][]` array pointer would be safe because ultimately it's a `char*` access which is strict-aliasing safe.  But if you want mixed 32 and 64-bit loads/stores that overlap or reload each other with the other size, that would violate strict-aliasing.

Comment: ... unless you use GNU C++ `typedef  uin32_t aliasing_unaligned_u32 __attribute__((may_alias, aligned(1)))`.

Comment: I wasn't explicit enough, the pointers are all `volatile` (= no memcpy).

Comment: I need 8b granularity (thus `uint8_t`) (8/16/32/64/__mm128 load/store) and still want to be able to select which buffer (0,1,2...,N). Why is `char [][]` different from `uint8_t[][]`?

Comment: Oh, then aliasing rules basically don't matter because every access has to actually be a store or load in asm, not optimized based on any analysis of what was recently stored there.   Probably just cast to `(volatile uint32_t*)`.  Hmm, I just realized you have an extra level of indirection, I think.  re: char: `uint8_t` *is* `unsigned char` on x86-64 C++ implementations, that's *why* it would be safe to alias `uint8_t*` and `uint32_t*` accesses to the same object.

Comment: Yeah, https://godbolt.org/z/Geha4n confirms that `uint8_t (*buffer)[16]` is the right way to declare buffer, if you want a pointer to a 2D array.  Remember that arrays decay to pointers.

Comment: I've made an error in my question (inversed 4 and 16), I edited the code. Thanks @PeterCordes for the explanation and the example code, .You can write an answer if you wish. I'll accept it.

Comment: Also, I expected the compiler to raise an error if trying to access an out-of-bound index.

Comment: *Also, I expected the compiler to raise an error if trying to access an out-of-bound index.* uh, good luck with that.  I guess you could use `volatile std::array<>` (of another `std::array`) and maybe a debug build would do bounds checking.  Or possibly `gcc -fsanitize=undefined` or one of the other sanitizer options would add bounds checking.

Comment: I see, I'll do without the checks first then.. thanks!